# How to customize list view for lara nova?

Tags: laravel-nova

I have nested pages for my project. For example, I have 'News' page. The page can have children. The hierarchy is following:

```
News
    Sport news
        Football
    Politics
        America
```

I have methods for getting children of a page. It's not a problem. My main problem is how to show it on UI. Currently I have this:
[image]

As you can see, it's not very convenient. A manager needs to track whole chain of ids to find a page. I would like to make some indents for children of a page to solve it:

[image]

So, I have two tasks. 
1) I need to show my sorted data on list page;
2) I need to make indents for child rows for showing hierarchy to a user.

Comment: Show us your code for the parent page.